# GlassFish 5.0 - Not a valid GlassFish Server installation

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I downloaded the GlassFish 5.0 from [here](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/index.html) because I was experiencing an issue with the JDBC connection pools in GlassFish 4.1.1 (and 4.0).

After unzipping the folder I tried to add the server to NetBeans and I received this error:

> Not a valid GlassFish Server installation.

The found one potential answer [here](https://forums.netbeans.org/post-168675.html), but it didn't seem to help.

I am able to add other versions of GF into fine. Also, GF 5.0 runs, and it has fixed the previous issue I described in 4.1.1 which is nice.

One thing I noticed was that when I changed the name of the console-core file here:

> glassfish4/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib/console-core-5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

to

> console-core-4.1.1.jar

NetBeans actually recognizes the GF installation! I tried to go through the entire GF installation and replace references to console-core-5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to console-core-4.4.1.jar, but after clicking "next" in the Add server dialog, it doesn't advance. I may have missed something, but it's still a major hack.

Comment: I ended up sticking with GF 4.1.1 and manually editing the domain.xml file to add the JDBC connection pools. So while I no longer need the answer to this question, I'm sure I am not the only one experiencing this issue!

Comment: did you fixed this issue? I am fighting with the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We stuck with 4.1.1, later migrating to WildFly.

Comment: Iam still stuck. Does it means I have to go back to 4.1?

Comment: Apparently it depends on [this](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/release82_base/glassfish.common/src/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/common/ServerDetails.java) piece of code. Depending on your Netbeans version, different GlassFish versions are detected. 8.2 recognizes GlassFish5. 8.1 did not have that pattern yet. If you are using Debian, most likely you want to update NetBeans manually instead of using the Debian repos. (At least at the time of writing this comment)

Answer (score 3):

I know its a late answer But it may help other new to this issue.

Rename the `console-core` jar file to have version name limited to 2 figure i.e. if jar name is `console-core-4.1.1` or `console-core-4.1.2` or something like it then change it to as
`console-core-4.1` which is in the directory in my case

```
E:\Programs\Java + Databases\java_ee_sdk-7u3\glassfish4\glassfish\lib\install\applications\__admingui\WEB-INF\lib
```

In my case in the above directory jar file name was `console-core-4.1.1` And I changed it to `console-core-4.1`. Now Everything is working fine.
Its working with Netbeans and in browser too with url

```
http://localhost:4848
```

Comment: This not work, the error does not longer appear but, when I press the "next" button for the next step, it does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I downloaded netbeans 8.02 and tried to add glassfish 5 server. After investigating for hours I found the solution. I had actually downloaded the Java EE bundle of netbeans 8.02 for installation. I uninstalled my netbeans and reinstalled using the Java ALL bundle installation file. Then the error went away.

Thanks,
Mitesh